# RDP Issues after docker update

Tags: debian, vpn, docker, rdp

I'm using Docker Containers with VPN Images which do a portforwarding. I'm connecting to the container published ports via RDP. After running this update

```
containerd.io/bookworm 1.6.27-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.6.26-1]
docker-buildx-plugin/bookworm 0.12.1-1~debian.12~bookworm amd64 [upgradable from: 0.11.2-1~debian.12~bookworm]
docker-ce-cli/bookworm 5:25.0.1-1~debian.12~bookworm amd64 [upgradable from: 5:24.0.7-1~debian.12~bookworm]
docker-ce-rootless-extras/bookworm 5:25.0.1-1~debian.12~bookworm amd64 [upgradable from: 5:24.0.7-1~debian.12~bookworm]
docker-ce/bookworm 5:25.0.1-1~debian.12~bookworm amd64 [upgradable from: 5:24.0.7-1~debian.12~bookworm]
docker-compose-plugin/bookworm 2.24.2-1~debian.12~bookworm amd64 [upgradable from: 2.21.0-1~debian.12~bookworm]
```

my client will keep on loosing the rdp connection sporadically while vpn is established and remote server as well as rdp port is reachable from the container.

Does someone have an idea on this?

Comment: Did you also updated the docker images using docker pull?

Comment: They're ubuntu:latest containers and automatically updated via watchtower, but the images arent the problem here i think.